# Watching for a message in an iframe

Tags: javascript, angularjs, iframe, dom-events

I'm wondering if there's a way in JavaScript/AngularJS to essentially look out for a message of some sort when it appears in an iframe. So say for example I have a form in an iframe, and I complete the form and it tells me I've completed it, is there a way to detect this via JS?

Any help/suggestions would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: is the iframe on same domain as page? If not you can't access inside it due to same origin policy

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Outside iframe listen event

```
      window.addEventListener( "message",
          function (e) {
                 alert(e.data);
              },false);
```

Within iframe trigger event

```
      window.postMessage('form complete');
```